# Why does my drill stop and start working when it feels like it?

Tags: drill

I have a makita drill that still works but sometimes stops working then starts working again. Any ideas what it could be?

Comment: What is the model number? Have you contacted Makita support?

Comment: "...feels like it"? - Please do not anthropomorphise power tools. They hate that.

Answer (score 3):

If it's a corded drill, that's a common sign that the cord is going bad and it's time to replace it. It might also be the power switch (see below).

If it's a battery drill then look to the power switch. Dirty contacts will cause intermittent power loss. You may just have to spray some contact cleaner into the switch assembly and work it a few dozen times, repeating the spray too, to get things working reliably. Battery contacts might also have gotten dirty. Clean them.

Comment: Guess I have to give this a + for corded drills or grinders that I fix every few weeks months, with all the flexing sometimes the conductors fail at the strain relief or within a few inches , I cut it off and it usually works.

Answer (score 3):

Badly worn brushes or worn/tired/broken brush springs will do this. They may be easy or hard to access, depending on the designer.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like your problem, but in my experience modern lithium-ions batteries just suddenly quit when they're out of juice unlike older ones which slowly loose power.

Comment: How are liion ,battery powered drill motors connected to cord connected drills motors in any way

Comment: @EdBeal I'm just sharing some knowledge, you don't have to be an ass about it